# How to do unit testing with django without hitting the database?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I am trying to test my models without actually accessing the database, but Django is apparently not able to create models when there are relationships and the associated instance is not in the database.

Is there a workaround around this?

### EDIT

This is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models

from app.models import Question, Category

user1 = auth_models.User(username='foo', first_name='Foo', last_name='Oof', email='foo@oof.com')
category = Category(name='sample-category')
question = Question(author=user1, category=category, title='sample-title')
```

Which gives:

```
$ python manage.py test app.unittests.test_models

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 209, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 121, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.loadTestsFromName(label)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "myapp/unittests/test_models.py", line 8, in <module>
    question = Question(author=user1, category=category, title='sample-title')
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 468, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "venv2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 668, in __set__
    (value, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name)
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: foo>": "User" instance isn't saved in the database.
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with these relationships if they are not in a table?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: They are in a table, *in production*. During model unit testing, I do not want to access the database: I just want to test the models. Apparently, because of the way that django is implemented, it is not possible to test the models in isolation. Is this correct?

Comment: But "in isolation" seems to be in conflict with "with relationships" here. You can certainly test the business logic of a single model without saving it, but of course if any of that logic access the database then, well, you need a database.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the problems do not arise when trying to save to the database (I am not doing such a thing in my unittests), but just when trying to instantiate a Model. Django refuses to do it, arguing that related models need to be in the database, *even* if you are only instantiating a model.

Comment: Please show an example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: added an example. As you can see, I am not saving my models, and django refuses.

Comment: Mocking, stubbing or otherwise faking the parts of the models you don't want to test might work, but can require a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Django tests do not hit your production database -- Django [creates a new database and destroys it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) after the tests have finished running.  If that's the case, does it matter whether you save your User model? Saving the User model will not affect your production database and the `test` command will clean up the temporary database that was created.

Comment: I do not want to test the database when testing models. Not even a test database. Testing models should be a simple and fast process, without huge external dependencies (like a database)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use factories; DjangoModelFactory and factory boy

factories.py

```
from factory import DjangoModelFactory, SubFactory
from factory import post_generation


class User(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'authapp.User'

    name = 'test_user...'


class Category(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'yourapp.Category'

    @post_generation
    def create_questions(self, create, **kwargs):
        count = 3

        make_items = getattr(Question, 'create' if create else 'build')
        items = [make_items(category=self) for i in range(count)]

        # for build you have to add questions to django's object cache
        if not create:
            self._prefetched_objects_cache = {'question': items}


class Question(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'yourapp.Question'

    category = SubFactory(Category)
    user = SubFactory(User)
```

tests.py:

```
category = Category.build()
```

This will create a category and 3 questions with a user. You can also not use SunFactories and create them separately, just use .build(); 
When using .build() you will not to hit database - build does call object's **init**() method but is not hitting a save() method

https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/